# How to add a wiki page through ItemAdded event receiver coding on the addition of a new item in a list?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I have a list named 'List1' in which I have 'title ' and 'WikiLink' columns. I want to add a wiki page on the addition of a new item using ItemAdded event receiver code and update the link on 'WikiLink' column. Please help me out in this. I have been stuck on this for quite a while.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

To create wiki page, you will have to add new item into one of the libraries that accepts wiki pages. Typically it's `Site Pages`, with code more less like this:

```
var l = (SPDocumentLibrary) SPContext.Current.Web.Lists["Site Pages"];
var folder = l.RootFolder;
var f = folder.Files.Add(string.Format("{0}/{1}", folder.ServerRelativeUrl.TrimEnd("/"), "MyWiki.aspx"), SPTemplateFileType.StandardPage);

//Site Absolute url + Site-relative Url, more info on MSDN.
var url = string.Format("{0}/{1}", SPContext.Current.Site.Url.TrimEnd("/"), f.Url);
```